# Give the matrix for T relative to the bases B and C

Tags: matrices

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong on this problem. 
Let B be the basis of R<sup>2</sup> given by $$\{\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\end{bmatrix}\}$$ Let C be the basis of R<sup>3</sup> given by $$\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-2\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}\}$$
Let T: R<sup>2</sup> --> R<sup>3</sup> be the transformation with standard martix $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -2 \\
        2 & 2  \\
        1 & 0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I did: $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -2 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
        2 & 2 & -1 & -1 & 4 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Row reduced and took the last two columns to get $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        -1 & 1  \\
        1 & 0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Did I not set this problem up correctly or something? No comments were made on this problem so I do not even have a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis vectors, so the matrix we want is $TB$ expressed relative to the $C$-basis. The matrix $C$ converts from the $C$-basis to the standard basis, so we left-multiply by its inverse to get $C^{-1}TB$ as our matrix.

To compute this, you can form the augmented matrix $\left[\begin{array}{c|c}C&TB\end{array}\right]$ and row-reduce it to get $\left[\begin{array}{c|c}I&C^{-1}TB\end{array}\right]$. Instead you’ve started with $\left[\begin{array}{c|c}C&T\end{array}\right]$ and ended up with $\left[\begin{array}{c|c}I&C^{-1}T\end{array}\right]$.